# Azure Serverless Function-Enabling CORS in response headers

Tags: javascript, azure, http-headers, cors

I've got a serverless function on Azure, written in Javascript, returning some HTML and front end JS. The JS is supposed to access a blob file hosted remotely. Right now, it's throwing me CORS errors. Even though I've added Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the headers:

```
headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://tif.azurewebsites.net',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'true',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers' 
                      }
```

The Content-Type header works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you set the CORS settings on Blob Storage? Since JS is accessing blobs from Blob Storage, I believe you would need to set the CORS for Storage.

Comment: Thanks, dude, that makes sense.What should I add for "allowed headers" and "exposed headers"?

Comment: Just go ahead with `*` for both "allowed headers" and "exposed headers".

Comment: That did it! If you add as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Correction-that worked for Edge, but on Chrome it still gives me the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://atpblob.blob.core.windows.net/imagedata/94ae9802-4e42-4ba1-8955-11ac7c7e3509.tif. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://tif.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Can you share the CORS setting?

Comment: Allowed origins: https://tif.azurewebsites.net/
Allowed methods: GET
* for header, maximum age =  5 seconds.

Comment: Is there anyway I can test it? May be call Function URL directly in the browser?

Comment: Hmm...That's weird. Can you share a screenshot of all the CORS settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146740/discussion-between-boris-k-and-gaurav-mantri).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, since your JS code is accessing the Blob Storage you would need to configure CORS settings for Blob Storage. When configuring CORS settings, please make sure that all settings are correct. A slight mismatch in the settings would result in 403 error returned from Storage Service.

Based on your environment, here's what I would recommend:

**Allowed Origins**: https://tif.azurewebsites.net

**Allowed Methods**: Select all of the methods.

**Allowed Headers**: *

**Exposed Headers**: *